# How to output an error message to the user and repeat to allow them to enter the word again if the user enters more than one word

Tags: java

Please Help!
If the user enters more than one word, output an error message to the user and repeat to allow them to enter the word again.

This is the code I have:

```
public void computeLetters(){
    for(int i = 0; i < term.length()-1; i++){
        if(term.charAt(i)==' ' && term.charAt(i+1)!=' ')
        numberWords = 1;
    }

    for(int numberWords = 1; numberWords > 0;){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please try again");
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter a word");
        numberWords = 0;
    }

    for(int numberWords = 0; numberWords < 1;){
        for(int j = 0; j < term.length()-1; j++){
                        numberLetters++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use a do while loop..

Answer (score 1):

A loop should work...

```
public void computeLetters()
{
    while (true) {
        // Get user input
        String term = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a word");
        if (null == term) return;
        // Check if more than 1 word (has a space)
        String [] words = term.split(" ");
        // Single word?
        if (words.length == 1) {
            // Get letter count
            int numberLetters = words[0].length();
            // Do something else here???
            // Done
            return;
        }
        // Show error message
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please try again");
        // And try again...
    }
}
```

Edit based on comment using only *if statements, loops or chars & strings* (and ints).

```
public void computeLetters()
{
    int numberLetters = 0;
    while (numberLetters == 0) {
        // Get user input
        String term = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a word");
        if (null != term) {
            // Check if more than 1 word (has a space)
            for (int i = 0; i < term.length(); i++) {
                if (' ' == term.charAt(i)) {
                    numberLetters = 0;
                    break;
                }
                numberLetters += 1;
            }
        }
        if (numberLetters == 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please try again");
        }
    }

    // Do something with numberLetters here....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I cannot use anything other than if statements, loops or chars & strings. My lecturer has recommended I do the word count in my app class. I am so close but just cant finish it. This is what I have: for(int i = 0; i < term.length()-1; i++){ if(term.charAt(i)==' ' && term.charAt(i+1)!=' '){ JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please try again"); JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter a word"); } }

Comment: I know I'm very sorry, I'm new to programming and to stackoverflow and I do apologise

Answer (score 0):

If this method is trying to get a single word from the user, validate it is one word, then count the number of letters in that word. This is how I would do it.

```
public int computeLetters()
 {

   String myWord = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter a single word.");
   while(myWord.contains(" "))
   {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("Cannot be more than one word.");
    myWord = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter a single word.");
   }
  return myWord.toCharArray().length;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply, I cant use arrays or contain method, only char, if statements and loops. Sorry I forgot to say that. This is what I currently have:
      for(int i = 0; i < term.length()-1; i++){
    if(term.charAt(i)==' ' && term.charAt(i+1)!=' '){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please try again");
     JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter a word");
    }
   }

Comment: Does it have to be only for loops as well? or are you allowed while loops? Also, what exactly is the method supposed to do? Was I right in assuming you want to get a word from the user then return the number of characters in that word?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what it's supposed to do! I am allowed to use while loops yes.: Develop an application that accepts a word from the user and calculates and outputs the number of letters in the word.
The application should check that only one word was entered.  If more than one word was entered,
the application should output a message to the user and repeat to allow them to enter the word again. I cannot use boolean, only if statements and loops. Thank you so much!

Comment: Ok, great! It looks like another user posted code that will work for your question. Just remember next time you post try and be more specific about the problem you are encountering!

Answer (score 0):

```
public void computeLetters(){
    numberWords = term.trim().split("\\s+").length;


    if(numberWords > 0 ){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please try again");
        term = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter a word");
        computeLetters();
    }

}
```

Number of words check, changed to a single line of code.

Next, the for loop in your code can be replaced by a simple 'if' as shown.

Then the next loop would have been an infinite loop. Just calling the function again after getting value from the user will do!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I cannot use anything other than if statements, loops or chars & strings. My lecturer has recommended I do the word count in my app class. I am so close but just cant finish it. This is what I have:       for(int i = 0; i < term.length()-1; i++){
    if(term.charAt(i)==' ' && term.charAt(i+1)!=' '){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please try again");
     JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter a word");
    }
   }